# How can I filter Windows Event logs by Task Category?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, event-log

I'm using PowerShell and "Get-WinEvent | ? { $_.Id -eq X }" to filter by IDs, but I really want to look at all events by their Task Categories as seen in the  Windows Event Viewer GUI application.

I have tried:

- Google for combinations of "windows event log", "task category", and "filter".
- SuperUser/Stack Overflow ([Why is the "Task category" drop down to filter a Windows event log disabled?](https://superuser.com/questions/838918/why-is-the-task-category-drop-down-to-filter-a-windows-event-log-disabled) is the closest related question)
- Every MSDN page I could find related to Windows Event Logs
- Everyone I know who also looks at Windows Event Logs

Comment: Just 5 minutes later I use Get-Member to figure out I need to use the TaskDisplayName property. "Get-WinEvent | ? { $_.TaskDisplayName -eq "Logon" }"